# Recent developments in the proof of fermat's last theorem

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

It's been 20 years since fermat's last theorem was proved by Andrew Wiles.
Has there been any simplification in proof in the last 20 years?
What I do only know is that different proofs of faltings's theorem were given by Vojta and Bombieri.

Comment: The main readable text is 'Gary Cornell, Joseph H. Silverman, Glenn Stevens - Modular forms and Fermat's last theorem (1997, Springer).djvu'

Comment: @reuns I wouldn't put a book written in 1997 in the "recent development" category.

Comment: Darmon, Diamond and Taylor published in 2009 this well written paper "Fermat's Last Theorem" (that infact I haven't read completely) that seems to simplify some facts, but they say it serves as an "introduction" to the work of Wiles.http://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Expository/05.DDT/paper.pdf

Comment: This question is probably better suited to MathOverflow. But two comments: 1) Khare-Wintenberger's proof of Serre's Conjecture gives a different proof of FLT. The proof uses many of Wiles' ideas, but is able to circumvent some of the black box inputs that Wiles used (see the first comment to [this blog post](https://xenaproject.wordpress.com/2019/09/27/does-anyone-know-a-proof-of-fermats-last-theorem/)). It's certainly not a simplification per se. 2) The abc conjecture would, if proven, give a completely different proof of FLT.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will look into Khare-Wintenberger's proof of Serre's Conjecture. Also, I'll post the same question on mathoverflow. I'll write the hyperlink in the comment after I post it.

Comment: I posted [it](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361714/recent-developments-in-the-proof-of-fermats-last-theorem) on mathoverflow.